# How is a / on the end of my url affecting css file inclusion?

Tags: php, css, mime-types

I'm new to this, but this week succeeded with nice code that works with `"/?page=2"` and stuff for a `$_GET[]`.

For speed and ease I'd been calling my file `index.php` so the url was either `testdomain` or `testdomain/` or `testdomain/?page=2`.

Today I changed my filename to `multi.php`.  Now, if anything follows that in the URL, I get an error

```
"The stylesheet 'http://testdomain/multi.php/mystyle.css' was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
```

So URL `testdomain/multi.php` works perfectly, `testdomain/multi.php/` does not.
I've tried as many recommendations about that error as I can find.

Comment: testdomain/multi.php points to a file. testdomain/multi.php/ points to a directory?

Comment: fixed the subject. ``\`` in the url is a whole different story than `/`. Other than that, you're saying that it doesn't work. You're right, it doesn't. What is the question? Do you want to know why it doesn't work, or do you want it to work somehow, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The '/' character is used in a string like that to symbolize a directory. Your code is looking at the file `multi.php` but treating it as if it is a directory.

If your file is located in testdomain then do the following:

```
http://testdomain/mystyle.css
```

The `.php` is indicating that that item is a file not a directory. You may however actually have a `multi` directory in which case you would access it like the following:

```
http://testdomain/multi/mystyle.css
```

Double check your file structure to verify that you have the correct path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Now I need to do the same with my image paths.  Isn't there a more generic way?  I thought "./mycss.css" would work, but doesn't.

Comment: @user1984559 Try two dots `../mycss.css`. A single dot means "in the current directory". Two dots means "in the parent or previous directory". See this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54900/what-do-and-mean-when-in-a-folder).

Comment: Good, but not good enough!  it wouldn't work for the URL "testdomain/multi.php".  I'm guessing this is why some sites are structured as directories and all the php files are called "index.php"

Comment: @user1984559 My apologies for that not working as well. How is your site/file system structured? If I can understand your structure I may be able to provide a more relevant answer.